# How to match regex the regex only at the beginning of each line?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the regex to match the word with colon present only at the beginning of each line:

```
/[^\r\n:-][^\r\n:]*:\s*/g
```

Following is the text I want to match with. The problem is, it also matches the 2nd Blah: on 3rd row. Which I don't want.

**Blah Blah:** dsfdffsdfsdfsds

**Blah:** dsffsffsdfsdfds

**Blah:** dsffsfds Blah:fsfsfssdfs

Comment: You should look at non-greedy quantifiers and the usage of `^` to match the beginning of your string.

Comment: Why not just use `^`? (with `m` flag)

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs  Not much experience with regex, how can I do that ?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs A negative character set with a greedy quantifier followed by a character not permitted by the set is definitely more efficient than lazy repetition - fewer steps are required.

Comment: /^[^\r\n:-][^\r\n:]*:\s*/gm worked for me. Somebody post it as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this regex ^[:] to do it.